# having issues understanding how to properly use functions in C-

Tags: c, function

I am currently a new programmer and I really dont know why these issues are occuring for me. I am supposed to create a program in C that will grab three temperatures given in fahrenheit and convert them in to celsius(and vice versa).

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
float calc_celsius(float new1, float new2, float new3);

int main()
{

float c1, c2, c3, f1, f2, f3;
/* float new1, new1, new3;
float newa, newb, newc; */

printf("Please type in three temperatures in fahrenheit");
scanf("%f %f %f", &f1, &f2, &f3);
/* new1 = calc_celsius(f1);
new2 = calc_celsius(f2);
new3 = calc_celsius(f3); */


printf("Please type in three temperatures in celcius");
scanf("%f %f %f", &c1, &c2, &c3);
newa = calc_fah(c1);
newb = calc_fah(c2);
newc = calc_fah(c3);

printf("The converted temperatures are: \t %.2f %.2f %.2f", calc_celsius(new1, new2, new3));
printf("The converted temperatures are: \t %.2f %.2f %.2f", calc_fahr(newa, newb, newc));


return 0;

}

float calc_celsius(float f1, float f2, float f3);

{

float new1 = ((f1 - 32) * .55);
float new2 = ((f2 - 32) * .55);

float new3 = ((f3 - 32) * .55);

return;

}

float calc_fahr(float c1, float c2, float c3)

{

float newa = (c1 * 1.8) + 32;
float newb = (c2 * 1.8) + 32;
float newc = (c3 * 1.8) + 32;

return;

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

forgot to add the error log

```
C:\Users\Britannia\Documents\assgn3.c||In function 'main':|
C:\Users\Britannia\Documents\assgn3.c|21|error: 'newa' undeclared (first use in this function)|
C:\Users\Britannia\Documents\assgn3.c|21|note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in|
C:\Users\Britannia\Documents\assgn3.c|22|error: 'newb' undeclared (first use in this function)|
C:\Users\Britannia\Documents\assgn3.c|23|error: 'newc' undeclared (first use in this function)|
C:\Users\Britannia\Documents\assgn3.c|25|error: 'new1' undeclared (first use in this function)|
C:\Users\Britannia\Documents\assgn3.c|25|error: 'new2' undeclared (first use in this function)|
C:\Users\Britannia\Documents\assgn3.c|25|error: 'new3' undeclared (first use in this function)|
C:\Users\Britannia\Documents\assgn3.c|35|error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token|
C:\Users\Britannia\Documents\assgn3.c|45|error: conflicting types for 'calc_fahr'|
C:\Users\Britannia\Documents\assgn3.c|26|note: previous implicit declaration of 'calc_fahr' was here|
||=== Build failed: 8 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

My new code is as follows and it functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
float calc_celsius( float );
float calc_fahr( float );
float printAll(float f1, float f2, float f3, float c1, float c2, float c3);

int main()
{

float c1, c2, c3, f1, f2, f3;

printf("Please type in three temperatures in fahrenheit \n");
scanf("%f %f %f", &f1, &f2, &f3);
printf("Please type in three temperatures in celsius \n");
scanf("%f %f %f", &c1, &c2, &c3);

printAll(f1, f2, f3, c1, c2, c3);

return 0;

}

float calc_celsius( float fahr )
{
  float celc = (fahr - 32) * .55;
  return celc;
}

float calc_fahr(float celc)

{

return celc * 1.8 + 32;

}

float printAll(float f1, float f2, float f3, float c1, float c2, float c3) {

printf("Fahrenheit \t | Celsius \n");
printf("***************************** \n");
printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", f1, calc_celsius(f1));
printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", f2, calc_celsius(f2));
printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", f3, calc_celsius(f3));

printf("The Temperature Conversions from Celsius to Fahreinheit are \n");
printf("Celsius \t | Fahrenheit \n");
printf("**************************** \n");
printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", c1, calc_fahr(c1));
printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", c2, calc_fahr(c2));
printf("%.2f \t\t %.2f \n", c3, calc_fahr(c3));

}
```

Comment: I highly recommend using descriptive variable names.  It will save you a lot of trouble while doing this kind of debugging.

Comment: Umm.. you commented out stuff and now it does not compile.   The error messages are very clear!

Comment: Why do you need the function to process all 3 at once? Just write a function that takes one Fahrenheit temperature and returns the Celcius conversion, and call it separately for each variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a function can only return one single value, not three as you expect here. You have many ways to get the three values in the "new" variables. One is defining them as global variables instead inside of the function, and the other one is pasing the variables by ref (with pointers) to the function in order to be able to change them inside the function. For the first method this is the especific code:

```
float new1, new1, new3;
float newa, newb, newc; 
int main()
{

float c1, c2, c3, f1, f2, f3;


printf("Please type in three temperatures in fahrenheit");
scanf("%f %f %f", &f1, &f2, &f3);


printf("Please type in three temperatures in celcius");
scanf("%f %f %f", &c1, &c2, &c3);

calc_celsius(f1, f2, f3)
printf("The converted temperatures are: \t %.2f %.2f %.2f", new1, new2, new3 );

calc_fahr(c1, c2, c3))
printf("The converted temperatures are: \t %.2f %.2f %.2f", newa, newb, newc);


return 0;

}

void calc_celsius(float f1, float f2, float f3);

{

new1 = ((f1 - 32) * .55);
new2 = ((f2 - 32) * .55);

new3 = ((f3 - 32) * .55);

}

void calc_fahr(float c1, float c2, float c3)

{

newa = (c1 * 1.8) + 32;
newb = (c2 * 1.8) + 32;
newc = (c3 * 1.8) + 32;

}
```

please note how the printf functions are used with the values and not with the function, and now your functions returns void because we do not need anithing.

With pointer should be something like this:

```
int main()
{

float c1, c2, c3, f1, f2, f3;


printf("Please type in three temperatures in fahrenheit");
scanf("%f %f %f", &f1, &f2, &f3);


printf("Please type in three temperatures in celcius");
scanf("%f %f %f", &c1, &c2, &c3);

calc_celsius(&f1, &f2, &f3)
printf("The converted temperatures are: \t %.2f %.2f %.2f", f1, f2, f3 );

calc_fahr(&c1, &c2, &c3))
printf("The converted temperatures are: \t %.2f %.2f %.2f", c1, c2, c3);


return 0;

}

void calc_celsius(float *f1, float *f2, float *f3);

{

*f1 = (((*f1) - 32) * .55);
*f2 = (((*f2) - 32) * .55);
*f3 = (((*f3) - 32) * .55);

}

void calc_fahr(float *c1, float *c2, float *c3)

{

*c1 = ((*c1) * 1.8) + 32;
*c2 = ((*c2) * 1.8) + 32;
*c3 = ((*c3) * 1.8) + 32;

}
```

Comment: of course, apart of it, your code is not compiling for sure, you have commented the declaration of the "new" variables"

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track here:

```
printf("Please type in three temperatures in fahrenheit");
scanf("%f %f %f", &f1, &f2, &f3);
/* new1 = calc_celsius(f1);
new2 = calc_celsius(f2);
new3 = calc_celsius(f3); */
```

You want to call the `calc_celcius` function for each input temperature as you originally did here.  The definition of the function would be

```
float calc_celcius( float fahr )
{
  float celc = (fahr - 32) * .55;
  return celc;
}
```

or even more simply,

```
float calc_celcius( float fahr )
{
  return (fahr - 32) * .55;
}
```

The definition for `calc_fahr` would be similar:

```
float calc_fahr( float celc )
{
  return celc * 1.8 + 32;
}
```

So your code would basically be:

```
printf("Please type in three temperatures in fahrenheit");
scanf("%f %f %f", &f1, &f2, &f3);
printf("The converted temperatures are: \t %.2f %.2f %.2f", 
          calc_celsius(f1),  // no real need to store any of these 
          calc_celcius(f2),  // results since you just print them
          calc_celcius(f3)); // out
```

with the same general structure for the Fahrenheit-to-Celcius calculations.

Some basic things to remember about functions in C:

1. A function must at least be *declared* before it can be called.  If the function and its caller are both in the same source file, I like to *define* the function before its caller.  In this case, that would look something like this:

   ```
   float calc_celcius( float fahr )
   {
     return (fahr - 32) * .55;
   }

   float calc_fahr( float celc )
   {
     return celc * 1.8 + 32;
   }

   int main( void )
   {
     // body of main, including calls to calc_celcius and calc_fahr
   }
   ```

   A function *declaration* will specify the function's return type, as well as the number and types of parameters<sup>1</sup>.  A function declaration does not need to specify the parameter names (although it's usually a good idea to do so).  The *declarations* for your conversion functions would look like this:

   ```
   float calc_celcius( float ); 
   float calc_fahr( float );
   ```

   So, if you wanted to, you could write your code as:

   ```
   float calc_celcius( float );

   int main( void )
   {
      ...
      x = calc_celsius( y );
      ...
   }

   float calc_celcius( float fahr )
   {
      return (fahr - 32) * .55;
   }
   ```

   if you wanted to put your function definitions after `main`.

   Variables declared locally to a function are not accessible to other functions; the bodies of `calc_celcius` and `calc_fahr` cannot update the `new1`, `new2`, `new3`, etc., variables which are local to `main`.  Similarly, variables declared locally in a function only exist for the lifetime of that function.  Variables declared at file scope (outside of any function) are visible to all the functions in that same translation unit.  Ideally, you want to avoid using globals and have functions communicate exlusively through parameters and return values.  It makes your code easier to maintain and reuse.

   Make sure the function declaration, function call, function definition, and function return all line up.  That is, if the function definition takes three parameters and returns a single float, then the `return` statement in the function needs to return a floating-point value, the function call needs to pass three parameters and assign the result to a `float` object, and that the return type and number and types of parameters between the declaration and definition match (the compiler will complain if any of these are incorrect).

---

<sup>1. This form of function declaration is known as *prototype syntax*.  Before the 1989 version of the standard, declarations only specified the return type of the function, so the compiler could not verify the number and types of parameters in the function call.  Non-prototype function declarations and definitions are archaic and (typically) not used in new development, but they are still legal and can be found in some old code bases.</sup>

Comment: okay thanks for the help! lets say i wanted to add in a function that prints all my results named printAll. How could i declare my celsius and fahrenheit functions inside of the printAll function? Or would I need to do something else

Comment: I got it actually, my question now is that can all functions access variables inside of main?

Comment: @theultima: Only if you pass a pointer to those variables as a parameter to those functions.  IOW, if `main` declares a local variable `a`, other functions cannot directly access `a`; you'd have to pass a pointer to `a` to those functions, such as `foo( &a );`.